# Router can ping google but firewall and PC's can't

Tags: networking, routes, firewall

we have a few problems trying to setup a network, we will try to explain what we got.

*These are the devices that we have:*

-ISP #1 modem

-ISP #2 modem

-Cisco Router 4331

-Cisco Firewall 5508

-Some switches

-An internal DNS Server and a few PC’s

*Network topology*

You can see the network diagram (the diagram is just to illustrate the topology).

*Actual status*

-The ISP #1 modem and the ISP #2 modem assign DHCP as show in images

-The Router **can** ping to ISP #1 modem and ISP #2 modem

-The Router **can** ping to google.com through ISP #1 modem and through ISP #2 modem

-The Firewall **can’t** ping to any ISP modem or google.com

-The PC’s **can’t** ping any ISP modem or google.com

**-This link contains a shared folder with attached files** (https://1drv.ms/f/s!AqkJyrRRfKHigetLlyGFtQ8RX_RpKg)

***Edit:***
Everything was solved by deleting the default network option!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the firewall the default gateway set to the router (192.168.4.247)?

It looks like PCs have the firewall as default gateway, which is correct. Also, the router has default routes as part of the DHCP negotiation with ISP#1 and ISP#2 modems. But nothing shows that the firewall knows where to send non-local packets.

Hope it helps!